# find unique values from a large file

Tags: c, algorithm, memory-management, hash, bigdata

I have a large file (say 10 terabytes) with stream of MD5 hashes (which contains duplicates), I am given a memory of 10MB(very limited) and unlimited hard disc space. Find all the unique hashes(eliminating duplicates) using given conditions. Please help, this is obviously not a homework question

Comment: "this is obviously not a homework question"

Comment: Does performance matter? I mean is it okay to use some O(n^2) solution?

Comment: @AdelQodmani The performance difference between O(n^2) and O(n*logn) for 10 *terabytes* worth of 16 byte hashes is astronomical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can sort the hashes with an external sorting algorithm (e.g. with a [polyphase merge sort](http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~rbaeza/handbook/algs/4/444.sort.c.html)), after which you just need to traverse the file and skip any hashes that equal the most recent hash

```
hash mostRecentHash;
while(fileHasHashes) {
    temp = fileWithDuplicates.readHash();
    if(!hashesAreEqual(mostRecentHash, temp)) {
        mostRecentHash = temp;
        fileWithoutDuplicates.writeHash(mostRecentHash);
    }
}
```

Comment: External polyphase merge sort is the *perfect* algorithm for this. +1

Comment: +1 Deleted my answer because this one is a much better solution.

Comment: then why he asked me to make use of unlimited database??

Comment: If you're supposed to use a database then just check to see if a hash is already in the database before adding it. `Select hash From hashes_table Where hash = currentHash`, and if that returns a null/false, then `Insert Into hashes_table (hash) Values (currentHash)`

Answer (score 3):

If performance doesn't matter, and your file system has no limits, then you can simply create a file for every hash. If during creation, you encounter `EEXIST`, then you have a duplicate, and it can be skipped.

```
for (each hash) {
    r = open(hash_to_filename(hash), O_CREAT|O_EXCL);
    if (r < 0) {
        if (errno == EEXIST) continue;
        perror(hash);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(r);
    output(hash);
}
```

The advantage of this is that it preserves the order of the hash values first occurrence in the stream.

The actual performance of this solution depends on the performance of the file system. If the files are organized in a B-Tree, then the performance will be roughly O(N log(N)). If the file system uses a hash table to organize the files, then the performance is expected to be O(N), but it depends on how often collisions occur (and the constant factor is high, because of the disk access).

Comment: This is obviously not a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

I like Zim-Zam's solution...proposing a small variation.

If we can assume that the fingerprints are distributed uniformly over the 128 bit space, then
can we use something like Bucket sort to bucket'ize the fingerprints into (smaller) bucket files, sort the bucket files individually and then merge the bucket files into one sorted file using a heap? This might reduce the nlogn cost.